# php image database blob

Tags: php, mysql, database, blob

need your help. I am able to upload image to database on a blob field. Now the question is I am not able to display it back, it just puts out a box with out the real image, what is that I am missing.
Here is the code. images is the field that is declared as blob;

```
$statement->bind_result($notes, $images, $image_type);
    $statement->fetch();
    echo $images;
    echo '<img rc="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($images).'"/>';
```

Comment: Well you cannot print the raw image and html together

Comment: so what is the fix or a solution to do what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missing 'r' in your attribute src `<img>` tag :

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($images).'"/>';
```

Answer (score 1):

you missed `src` from img tag. use src in place of rc

```
  echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($images).'"/>';
```